# UDP (client A) three way handshake TCP (client B)?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I would like to ask, if anyone had dealt with a similar situation?

Client A sends data via UDP, Client B receives the data via TCP.. But we started to face an issue when TCP sends a ACK message to UDP and if it fails, client A keeps sending same message over and over again (and current systems setup process all packages) causing not just duplicate records, but also a performance issues and etc.

Can anyone advise what would be the best way to address the above issue? Currently I am thinking of implementing some set of rules (if error/connection error for ACK msg to UDP when don't process a message and send ACK again).

Overview:

- Client A (GSM Based device used to transmit a data)
- Client B (Socket Server TCP) used for delivering/processing data to the platform.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Makes no sense. If you need to handle UPD data, make a UDP listener, not TCP.

Comment: I second Mat. I am wondering how you actually did that. And you should add what languages you are using. Maybe some code.

Comment: A UDP endpoint cannot talk to a TCP endpoint.  Period.  Some us some code so we can see what you're really doing.

Comment: Language C#, the process like is this - device udp sends data  when we get a message to  socket tcp decodes header, sends ack msg to udp device, then tcp decodes a message and processes it.

I appreciate that it makes no sense, it does not make too much to me either but have to find a way how to avoid failed ack msg issues as described above.

Comment: Post some code, or at least a Wireshark trace.  It can't possibly be working the way you think it is.